# Error in modelformset_factory : matching query does not exist

Tags: django, formset

I have these 3 models:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30L, blank=True) 


class ServiceUser(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=False, blank=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=False, blank=False) 


class SupplierPrice(models.Model):
    service_user = models.ForeignKey('ServiceUser') 
    price_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PRICE_TYPES) 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
```

I want to create a modelformset_factory with SupplierPrice as model.

The modelformset_factory works perfectly on  Service and ServiceUser models. But if I do:

```
>>> prices = SupplierPrice.objects.filter(service_user = srvuser)
```

which is a queryset that returns two objects SupplierPrice, and:

```
>>> SupplierPriceFormSet = modelformset_factory(SupplierPrice)
>>> pricesformset = SupplierPriceFormSet(queryset=prices)
>>> pricesformset.as_p()
```

It returns a DoesNotExist error : Service matching query does not exist. I must have misunderstood something but what?

Comment: Can you show how you're declaring `SupplierPriceFormSet`? Your code above shows `ServiceUserFormSet` for a different model.

Comment: right! I've just edited the post with the correct line.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, then. The exception implies that it's looking for a `Service` instance - is it possible that one of your `ServiceUser` instances has an FK to a `Service` that does not exist, say because you're using a legacy database or a database that does not enforce FK constraints? Full exception text might help too.

Comment: I'm looking in my MySql db to see what is wrong. The FK is not clearly defined in MySQL since I'm using a pre-existinq DB to my project.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper It was as you thought some insanity in the DB. But I'm really surprised about the time it takes to build the formset since there is only two rows. Have you an idea about what's wrong with that?

Comment: Does your ServiceUser class use its service attribute in its unicode representation? The formset will have a select widget allowing you to change which user the price is for, with all known users as choices - so if any of them need a missing service to generate the label you would see this exception.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs because of some errors in the referential integrity of my DB. I had to clean it up first in order to have the modelformset_factory working.

Thanks to PeterDeGlopper ! After that, the rendering slowness of the modelform_factory came from an over complex unicode model method.